# Auto Refresh a Html table every x seconds

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

I am attempting to refresh a table i have as the variables in there are constantly updated and i want to re-update those variable every few seconds. I have already done up code on my part by giving the table an id and creating a div for it. The code will explain what i actually. Thanks in Advance ! **EDITED: Added Var Table and Var Refresher. however the code still wont reload my table !Any ideas??**

Test.php

```
       <html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
 var table = $('#tableID');

// refresh every 5 seconds
var refresher = setInterval(function() {
  table.load("1103242B/processing/js.php");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  clearTimeout(refresher);
}, 1800000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once'js.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

JS.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
include 'start.php';
include 'functions.php';
header("Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store");

$query = "SELECT * FROM opentrades"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border = '1px' id='tableID'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<tr><td>" . "Order Number" . "</td><td>" . "Selection" . "</td><td>" . "Date" . "</td><td>" . "Type" . "</td><td>" . "Size" . "</td><td>" . "Bid Price" . "</td><td>" . "Offer Price" . "</td><td>" ."Stop Loss" . "</td><td>" . "Take Profit" . "</td><td>" ."Profit/Loss(USD)"."</td><td>" ."Close"."</td></tr>" ;  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
if ($row['selection']=='eur/usd')// TO RETRIEVE BID AND OFFER FOR EACH ROW
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid;

      $offerpricepl=$bid1;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/jpy')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid2;

      $offerpricepl=$bid3;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/cad')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid4;

      $offerpricepl=$bid5;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/jpy')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid6;

      $offerpricepl=$bid7;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/chf')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid8;

      $offerpricepl=$bid9;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='gbp/usd')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid10;

      $offerpricepl=$bid11;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='aud/usd')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid12;

      $offerpricepl=$bid13;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/chf')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid14;

      $offerpricepl=$bid15;

      }
  if ($row['type']=="buy")
    {

      $minipipskiller='10';
      $offeropen=$row['offerprice'];
      $pips=$offerpricepl-$offeropen;
      $closedb=$offeropen;
      $pips1=round($pips, 6);
      $pips2 = str_replace('.', '', $pips1);
        if ($pips2<0)
      {
        $pips2 = str_replace('-', '', $pips2);
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
        $pips2 = -1 * abs($pips2);
      }
      else {
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
      }
      $pips3=$pips2/$minipipskiller;
    }// PIP COUNTING
  elseif ($row['type']=="sell")//FOR PIP COUNTING
    {

      $minipipskiller='10';
      $bidopen=$row['bidprice'];
      $pips=$bidopen-$bidpricepl;
      $closedb=$bidopen;
      $pips1=round($pips, 6);
      $pips2 = str_replace('.', '', $pips1);
      if ($pips2<0)
      {
        $pips2 = str_replace('-', '', $pips2);
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
        $pips2 = -1 * abs($pips2);
      }
      else {
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
      }
      $pips3=$pips2/$minipipskiller;
    }



      $ticksize= "0.0001";// FOR PROFIT AND LOSS
      $lot1 = "100000";
      $sizecalc=$row['size'] * $lot1;

        if ($row['type']=="buy")
      { 
        $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
      }
      if ($row['type']=="sell")
      {
        $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
      }

      $zero= '0';

      if($profitandloss<$zero) {
            $profitText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
        } elseif ($profitandloss>$zero) {
            $profitText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
        }


$sum+= $profitandloss;


    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] .         
        "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . 
        "</td><td>" . $row['date'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['type'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['size'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] .
        "</td><td>" . $profitText . 
        "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".
        $row['trade_id']."'>X</a>
       </td></tr>";  
$profitandloss=0;

if($sum<$zero) {
    $sumText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$sum</div>";
} elseif ($sum>$zero) {
    $sumText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$sum</div>";
}
}

echo "</table><br>";



?>
```

Comment: Replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. Use `$("table.your-table").load()` and simply echo out the contents(!) of the table on the `js.php` (so no `<table>` stuff)

Comment: Where exactly is your error? What does not work as expected?

Comment: The dynamic variables in the table does not refresh..

Comment: just a guess: the response may be cached by the browser. So in your PHP you should add: header("Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store")

Comment: A lot of other things to improve here. It's ugly to return HTML - use a data only format like JSON or XML. Maybe one day you want to write an iOS, Andoid app or any other native client. Then the HTML table is pretty useless. And if its HTML, never specify border or style directly - use css.

Comment: Any way to test out if the refreshing works before testing it on a table???

Comment: Google Chrome can be very helpful here. Go to your page, open Tools -> Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), then select Network. Now you can inspect every request. If it says "(from cache)" in column Size then you have no refresh.

Comment: The jQuery library is missing. add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) with [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is the one you're looking for

```
var table = $("#tableID");

// refresh every 5 seconds
var refresher = setInterval(function() {
  table.load("/path/to/js.php");
}, 5000);
```

Or shorten it up with

```
var refresher = setInterval(table.load.bind(table, "/path/to/data"), 5000);
```

If you'd ever like to stop refreshing the data, (e.g.,) say the user leaves the page open for a long time

```
// stop refreshing after 30 minutes
setTimeout(function() {
  clearTimeout(refresher);
}, 1800000);
```

---

If your data load takes a while, you might want to only refresh X seconds **after** the data is loaded. You could do that like this using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
var table = $("#tableID");

var refresh = function() {
  table.load("/path/to/js.php", function() {
    setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
  });
};

refresh();
```

Comment: Yes, `/path/to/js.php`. It should return HTML as described by [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: ps. don't use uppercase names in your URLs.

Comment: I have edited the code already! but the table still does not refreshes. I have checked with the dynamic varaibles , they are updating every second if i tried refreshing to see!.

Comment: Thanks for your replies anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents, but this just seems like an unnecessary load to hit your db with. 
I would consider something like a trigger and write to something less expensive like a

```
bool = timestamp > now;
  or
if(myhash != tablehash)
```

So your long polling is just asking if something has changed and not running the query

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer the stated question, it still offers very relevant and useful insight related to the question.  At least it did for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#tableID').replaceWith($(data));
```

Into

```
$('#tableID').replaceWith(data);
```

Although the thing you do is loading some things into an element. So semantically speaking using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) sounds better.

```
$('#tableID').load('some/url/file.php')
```

Comment: how do i actually do this? where do i insert it? $('#tableID').load('some/url/file.php')