# Automatically refresh table from included .php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to get a table to refresh without the page being refreshed.
I know this can be done with AJAX but I can't seem to get it working.
This is my situation:
I have a main.php page which has an include (table.php). This include contains a table id: tablevisit. This table is dynamically being made: it loops through every row in the database. This is table.php

```
echo "<div id='tableContainer'>";



$con = new mysqli("localhost","sample","samplepass","sample");  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sampletable";
$i = 0;

$dyn_table = '<table border="1" cellpadding="10" class="visitorlist" id="tablevisit">'; 

$query = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $name = $row['address'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $time = $row['time'];
        $url = $row['visit_url'];
        $urlstring = $row['visit_url'];


        if($i % 3 == 0){ 
            $dyn_table .= '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td>'.$date.'</td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td>'.$time.'</td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td class="tdshort"><a href='.$url.' target = "_blank" class=" tdoverflow">' . $_SESSION['cuttedurl'] . '</a></td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td><button type= "button" name = "' . $id . '"  class="dynamixbutton navbar-button btn-danger btn" post_id="' . $id . '" type="submit" >CHAT</button></td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td>' . $id . '</td>';


        }
        else {
            $dyn_table .= '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td>'.$date.'</td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td>'.$time.'</td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td><a href='.$url.' target = "_blank" class=" tdoverflow">' . $_SESSION['cuttedurl'] . '</a></td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td><button type= "button" name = "' . $id . '" class="dynamixbutton navbar-button btn-danger btn" post_id="' . $id . '" type="submit">CHAT</button></td>';
            $dyn_table .= '<td>' . $id . '</td>';

        }
        $i++;

    }
$dyn_table .='</tr></table>'; 
echo "</div>";
```

On main.php `echo $dyn_table;` is called.
Now, $dyn_table needs to be called every x seconds. How does one do this? 
I've tried just refreshing the table but I thought it would be better to just call $dyn_table every x seconds.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153535/refresh-a-part-of-webpage-in-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320234/auto-refresh-a-html-table-every-x-seconds) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600166/auto-refresh-included-php-file-inside-a-div) but it did not work out for me. And those were html elements, not PHP variables.
Any suggestions? Recommendations, tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your PHP file is just creating an empty div and storing the data in a variable. You haven't got a call back to the `$dyn_table`. Try sticking `echo $dyn_table;` somewhere near the bottom (maybe the line above `echo "</div>";`

Comment: @Tom I've tried to echo `$dyn_table;` within the div. Unfortunately, it did not work. Just to be sure; `echo $dyn_table;` is present in main.php, and main.php includes table.php which is the code above.

Comment: where is your ajax code ? call the same page from ajax and replace the body > data of current doc with that ajax data

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question i believe you got no clue on how ajax works. Maybe this might help you.

In pseudo code it looks like this:

```
whenajaxrequestwassuccessfull (var tabledata = getDataFromServerViaAjax('http://URL of The PHP File which echos a json formated data string')) {

  var dataobject = convertjsontoobject(tabledata);

  loop over the table {
    tablerow->tablefield->setData(dataobject->somedetail)

  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I only know a little bit of AJAX. I'm trying to learn it haha. I will look at this.